# Automatically delete temporary files in child process in perl

Tags: perl, unlink

I am forking in a perl script and exiting from parent process after `fork()`.
In child process, then I am creating temporary files by this method in a function

```
my ( $S_TEMP_FILE,  $stmpfile )  = tempfile( UNLINK => 1, DIR => $TMPDIR );
```

Now the issue is that this temporary file is not getting deleted automatically when I am exiting from function. I have created some temporary files before forking too, but they are getting automatically deleted on exit of functions.I have gone through all the links regarding this but i am not able to figure out the reason for this behaviour.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] that includes the forking and creating in both the parent and the child process.

Answer (score 4):

Files created by `tempfile` are "automatically removed when the program exits", not when some subroutine exits.

Note that if the program calls `_exit` or if it's killed by a signal, the program won't get a chance to delete these files.

If you want the file to be deleted sooner, you'll need to delete it yourself or use `File::Temp->new()` instead of `tempfile`. (Files created by `File::Temp->new()` are be deleted when the object is destroyed.)

Comment: Thanks for the help.Also is there any specific difference between creating temporary files by these two methods?

Comment: That's the only one

Comment: @SanchitaGhai: Kindly consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work